# Should we burninate the [equivalent] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I used a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734730/c-equivalent-of-node-js?noredirect=1#comment90430383_51734730) with the [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equivalent) tag and it got put on hold with the reason being that

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it."

The equivalent tag description being:

> This tag is used for questions about similarities between any of various
>   programming constructs. Comparisons include correspondences between API,
>   functionality, syntax, features, methodologies and the like.

The tag doesn't seem to fit into the second [rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) and the tag itself is illegal because it doesn't signify a problem. Should we burninate it?

Comment: Looks like a meta tag to me and should be burninated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on a sample of the 313 Qs involved, the majority tagged [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equivalent) are off topic, usually for being [code translation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/1505120) Qs *without* the English explanation. 24 are already Closed and others should be for a variety of reasons other than requesting code translation, such as Unclear, Too broad, and Primarily opinion-based, or off-topic for requesting a recommendation.

The tag should probably be burninated for being a magnet for such a high proportion of unsuitable Qs but a thorough review might establish that there is a theme to the Qs that belong on SO and a revision to the Usage guide might be worth attempting before deciding whether or not to proceed to burnination. For some of the Qs that appear to belong on SO the tag does not seem to add value.

In addition to a Usage guide the tag has 3 watchers.

To begin with the tag should be cleaned up through the routine application of edits, Close and Delete votes … but not (yet) burninated.

<sup>Afterthought</sup> It is quite possible that Closures and Deletes, if completed before many additional applications of this tag, may drop the total number of instances below the threshold for triggering the full burnination process.

Answer (score -3):

What if you know how to do something in one language, and want to find the equivalent of that in another language (because you are learning the new language)?

Whereas your question was on about recommending a tool, there are many on-topic questions that are about how to do things in other languages, that they know how to do in one.

These are the types of questions that I mean:

- [equivalent findAll python method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610511/equivalent-findall-python-method-in-java)
- [What is the alternative equivalent of Javascript “prototype” in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830130/what-is-the-alternative-equivalent-of-javascript-prototype-in-typescript)
- [mruby equivalent of begin … end until](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181401/mruby-equivalent-of-begin-end-until)
- [Java Regular Expressions equivalent to PCRE/etc. shorthand `\K`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265668/java-regular-expressions-equivalent-to-pcre-etc-shorthand-k)

Comment: I don't think the "equivalent" tag is important for questions like that.  The functionality of the feature is what's important - the fact that it's similar to a feature in a different language is just a convenient shorthand to describe what you're looking for, and if you can describe it in sufficient detail then you don't even need to mention the other language at all.

Comment: Just playing devils advocate a little here - I see a purpose for the tag whereby those watching questions where they know a few languages, and will happily help convert code from one to the other, and this gives the ability to do that, however there is the ability to search the title and body for "equivalent" too, and include tags for the languages of which they are knowledgeable. There are arguments both for and against this tag, is what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @KyleFairns I agree with you on the coding constructs. However, I don't know what I am looking for. Is looking for a built-in library that can accessed with the #include statement asking for a tool? These libraries are a vital part of C++. Is equivalent more illegal for C++ than other languages because of the necessity of the #include statement?

Comment: @BrendonShaw You were asking for an equivalent of node.js for C, which is not a question for stack overflow (which is a site for when you have a programming problem, have attempted something, and have a problem to be solved at that point). Maybe you were looking for something more like the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) SE site?

Comment: If there is a problem that you have, then specify the problem, rather than asking for a library that does it, and the answerers will try to solve your problem (often using libraries themselves). The intent behind the question shouldn't be "I need a library for this", it should be "Here's my problem, here's what I've tried, can you help me?"

Comment: @KyleFairns Thanks for the website! I needed that.

Comment: Still, asking for similarities in coding constructs doesn't seem like a problem. I think the tag should still be burninated.

Comment: If you know how to express your intent in one language, but another language is subtly different, or (as in the case of the regex question linked) has different functionality with varying implementations, asking for an equivalent seems very reasonable in my books. There are some cases where the asker knows exactly what they want to express, and can do so in language x, but are unable to in language y, and so asking for help to express that in a language they are less familiar with also seems reasonable. But more to the point, it definitely seems on topic for SO

Comment: @Kyle there is already [language-comparisons] tag which is being used for this kind of questions among others

Comment: @artem then couldn't it also make sense to make [tag:equivalent] a synonym of [tag:language-comparisons]?