# Shouldn't "convert sql query to ORM" questions be duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I am following the [Laravel tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) every day, and I see this type of questions from time to time, maybe have seen them 20 times or more.

The title is always something like this:

> **Convert/Translate (raw) SQL/MySQL query to Eloquent ORM**

I assume [eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eloquent) might be replaced by other [ORMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine) or [knex.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knex.js) in other languages.

Here are some examples:

- *[Translate MySQL group by date and select count query to Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58734556/5581565)*
- [Convert SQL query to Laravel Query Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53701567/5581565)
- [How can I convert this SQL query to Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56827639/5581565)
- *[Convert SQL query to Query builder Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51839174/5581565)*
- *[I want to convert a MySQL query into a Laravel ORM query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58764131/5581565)*

I understand that these questions are different, because it's always a different SQL query *obviously*.

But they all don't show any effort; just paste a block of SQL statement(s) and ask to get it converted for you.

There's even an [online tool](https://sql2builder.github.io/) for this, and these questions are highly unlikely to be helpful to anyone else in the future, because the title is usually too broad and the SQL is specific to the OP's problem.

I stumbled upon a user with the [MySQL tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) gold badge who answered a question of this sort with another SQL statement. I commented that I would close the question as duplicate if I were in their shoes, but they disagreed on the latter.

I don't know whether am allowed to link to that comment or not.

#### Should I vote to close such questions as duplicates or not?

*Yes, I already laughed at the possible irony of this question itself being a duplicate*

Comment: Are you also the person going around closing any php question with any php error message in it as duplicate?  After all, there is already an answer of how to trouble shoot error messages.

Comment: *"Don't know whether am allowed to link to that comment"* .. I don't think you were not allowed to, but I also don't see the point in doing so, it wouldn't add much.

Comment: I don't have any tag specific gold badge yet, so no and I would never close a question as duplicate if I didn't find an answer I was going to write already written (if I could that is)

Comment: Regarding dupe:  It might be useful to create a Q&A where the answer explains in general how to convert SQL to Eloquent and then use that as the dupe target. Using other specific questions with a similar task would be an odd dupe target, imo.

Comment: @Tom so something like [Regex Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) but for converting SQL statements to *any?* ORM

Comment: I don't know these PHP ORM libraries, so I can't tell if they are similar enough to handle several of them without making the Q&A too broad. I would start with the most prominent ORM system and then later adapt the answer (or add other answers) if that fits.

Comment: See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/7296893). Seems to me these are just code translation questions without an attempt and thus off-topic. While we could provide a canonical with general translation advice, that's likely not beneficial since people tend to get mad when their question gets marked as a duplicate that doesn't cover their specific issue

Comment: @ErikA Help Vampires getting mad should not be on the list of concerns when thinking about creating a canonical Q&A. I would first think if there already exists something like this and would it be helpful for people search for stuff like that.

Comment: I think it can be helpful, the instructions would be almost standard given that OP would know the basics of that ORM

Comment: @Tom It isn't just help vampires to worry about, it's the high rep, gold badge wielding enablers that want every question to have a home on Stack Overflow that have a hand in the problem. "It's not a duplicate because it doesn't address this specific SQL statement in this specific context and plus I answered it and am getting upvotes"...

Comment: It happened again today, a gold badger edited the question and upvoted it to 0 after I linked to this meta in a comment, a move I can only interpret as "This question is valid despite it being a code translation service request"

Comment: @HereticMonkey Well yes, that is also a big problem and maybe even worse, due to the additional moderation rights.

Comment: It is just normal for the [sql] tags.  [regex] has this problem as well.  Core issue is that Google just isn't very helpful when programmers search for solutions.  Or duplicates for that matter.  If you know a duplicate then just vote it.  But you'll burn out after a while, it never stops, then you add these tags to the Ignored Tags section in your profile..